# How to set "background: none" with Tailwind CSS

Tags: css, tailwind-css

How do I set `background: none` with Tailwind?

`bg-none` sets `background-image: none` (see the [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image)), which can have different behavior.

Comment: What about using bg-opacity-0

Answer (score 4):

I like to use `bg-transparent` This is only really useful when trying to remove the background color/image from an element that already has a background colour/image on it for some other reason, if you don't declare background color at all the element will never have one (obviously)